# how to filter hours from one timestamp and placing that hours into another timestamp in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have one timestamp e.g., `t1 = 1364571300` which is `29/3/2013 16:35:00` (in my local timezone (CET)).

From **t1**, I only want to get  hours which is `16:35:00`

Then I have another timestamp: e.g., `t2 = 1364598000` which is `30/3/2013 0:00:00` (in my local timezone (CET)).

Now, I want to replace the hours of **t2**  with (`16:35:00`) from **t1** so that the final result will give me a new time stamp `t3` which will be `30/3/2013 16:35:00` (in my local timezone (CET)).

How do I do that?

Comment: What does the `java` tag have to do with this?

Comment: how to do it in java/javascript

Comment: @ Yasin: Well, do you want to do it in JavaScript (which is one language), or Java (an *entirely different* language with an *entirely different* set of library functions)? Or do you not care which one?

Comment: i want to know how to do it..language is not important here..i tagged to attract a larger community that's all

Comment: @ Yasin: Language is **very** important here, because the answers will be completely different, because (as I said), the two languages have completely different date-related library functions available. You may as well throw `C#`, `C++`, and `Scheme` into the mix while you're at it...

Comment: is new time stamp  `3/30/2013 16:35:00` or `30/3/2013 16:35:00` ?

Comment: @rab: 30/3/2013 16:35:00 sorry for the mistake

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Im working with JS

Comment: @Yasin: I've removed the irrelevant `java` tag, then.

Comment: @Yasin: The unix timestamp 1364598000 is Friday, March 29, 2013, at 23:00 (UTC), **not** Saturday, March 30, 2013 at 00:00. That would be your local time zone (which apparently is GMT+1). I've updated the question for you. It matters.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: thanks. Where is your answer? it's not visible anymore..anyways sann's answer is giving the correct result

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: sans script is giving the correct answer but the timezone has changed. Iam getting: Thu Mar 30 113 16:35:00 GMT+0200 (CEST). Do you know why?

Comment: @Yasin: Yes, because Sann's script is not guaranteed to parse the string he's creating using local time. It could be local, it could be UTC, it's up to the browser (and therefore may vary from browser to browser). I've fixed my answer, which uses only specified behavior according to the spec so we don't have that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var t1 = new Date(1364571300 * 1000);
var t2 = new Date(1364598000 * 1000);
var t3 = new Date(t2.getFullYear(), t2.getMonth(),   t2.getDate(),
                  t1.getHours(),    t1.getMinutes(), t1.getSeconds(), t1.getMilliseconds());
```

That uses the [`Date(Number)` constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) to create your two dates (note that it accepts milliseconds rather than seconds), and then the [`Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)` constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) to build a date from the parts of the two days you want.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uxadin/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uxadin/1/edit) [**Note** to anyone using that example: Remember that the times are *local*, so what's 16:35 to Yasin may be a completely different time to you (or even a different date, in the case of her `t2` — for me, that's March 29th at 23:00, not March 30th at 00:00, because I'm on GMT and she's on GMT+0100).]

And answering your other question somewhere in the comments, if you want to get the Unix timestamp value (seconds since The Epoch) from `t3`, you'd do that like this:

```
var timestamp = t3.getTime() / 1000; // Converts milliseconds to seconds
```

Comment: Im getting Fri Mar 29 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) in my console.log(d3). can you please explain how to get the correct output?

Comment: @Yasin: The values you've quoted don't have the times you've quoted. The unix timestamp 1364598000 is Fri Mar 29 2013 23:00:00 UTC, **not** Sat Mar 30 2013 00:00:00. That would be your local timezone.

Comment: I used this site: http://www.timestamp.fr/?

Comment: @Yasin: My answer was actually correct, except I was taking the time from your *second* date and putting it on your first. You wanted it the other way around. Fixed.

Comment: @Yasin: You're welcome, glad that helped (and I learned something).

Comment: @Yasin: It's best to post a new question for a new question. :-)

Comment: ok im doing it thanks

Comment: i will post my full query. now you will understand why i posted this question

Comment: @TJ i want to put two question in 1..may be the admins will block my question? but asking separately will not give the complete picture. What do you suggest?

Comment: I have decided to post it part by part..here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718779/jquery-using-a-variable-outside-of-the-scope-of-the-function

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
var t1 = new Date(1364571300 * 1000);
var t2 = new Date(1364598000 * 1000);
var time = t1.getHours() + ':' + t1.getMinutes() + ':' + t1.getSeconds();
var newdate = (t2.getMonth()+1).toString() + '/' + t2.getDate().toString() + '/' + t2.getYear().toString();
var t3 = new Date(newdate+' '+time);
```

Use `t3`. It stores the desired date.

Comment: it tried to see the output with console.log(t3); and it's giving Fri Jan 16 1970 20:02:51 GMT+0100 (CET)

Comment: @Yasin Multiply your timestamps with 1000 so you get the Microseconds from 01.01.1970 as used in Javascript. I expect you use the timestamp from PHP where seconds used from this date.

Comment: If I do test= Math.round(Date.parse(t3)/ 1000);
                    console.log(test); it gives -58593576300 ?? do you know how to get the correct unix timestamp from t3?

Comment: @Yasin: Can I suggest you step back and actually do some reading on JavaScript? `Date.parse` is for turning a string into a number, it has nothing to do with getting the underlying unix timestamp. `t3.getTime() / 1000` will give you that.

Comment: @Sann: The problem here is that you're relying on non-standard date parsing in `new Date(...)`. That format is not specified, which means we don't know whether it will be parsed in local time or UTC (and it could well be different on different browsers, since again it's non-standard). So it's going to be more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

my time is GMT+0530 .

```
function getUtcDate( t ) {

    var d    = new Date( t  * 1000 )
    var ut  = (+d) + ( d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000 ) + ( 60*60* 1000 ) ;
    return new Date( ut );

};

function getDiff( d ) {

   return +d - +new Date( d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay() );    

}

var d1    = getUtcDate( 1364571300 );
var d2    = getUtcDate( 1364598000 );

var diff1 = getDiff( d1 );
var diff2 = getDiff( d2 );

var t3 =  (+d2 - diff2) + diff1 ;

console.log( new Date( t3 ) ) ;
```

which prints

```
Date {Sat Mar 30 2013 16:35:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}
```