# JQuery- using a variable outside of the scope of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery function:

```
jQuery(function() {
                jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
                    onSelect: function(value) { 
                        alert('The chosen date is ' + value); 
                        currentDate= Math.round(Date.parse(value)/ 1000);

                    } 
                });

                // TODO
                // on select of a time value trigger the action 
                jQuery("#timepicker").timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i'}) 
                val = jQuery("#timepicker").val();
                currentTime= Math.round(Date.parse(val)/ 1000);

                var t1 = new Date(currentTime * 1000);
                var t2 = new Date(1364598000 * 1000);
                var t3 = new Date(t2.getFullYear(), t2.getMonth(),   t2.getDate(),
                                     t1.getHours(),    t1.getMinutes(), t1.getSeconds(), t1.getMilliseconds());
                console.log(t3);
                var timestamp = t3.getTime() / 1000;
                });
```

My questions is:

In "**var t2**" instead of a fixed value how can I use "**var currentDate**" ?

More precisely,
I want to use the **value** from `onSelect: function(value)`  in t2.

That means whenever a new value is assigned to **currentDate**, i want it to be passed in **t2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare it outside the function:

```
            var currentDate; //declare outside function
            jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
                onSelect: function(value) { 
                    alert('The chosen date is ' + value); 
                    currentDate= Math.round(Date.parse(value)/ 1000);

                } 
            });
```

Comment: declaring outside is not solving the problem..because inside date picker the value is assigned after the click..so when i do a console.log(currentDate) outside of the datepicker function, it's telling undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function() {

var currentDate;//declaration of currentDate 

          jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
                onSelect: function(value) { 
                    alert('The chosen date is ' + value); 
                    currentDate= Math.round(Date.parse(value)/ 1000);

                } 
            });
```

you can declare like this.

Comment: then when i use currentDate in t2, it does not work...i want the value of currentDate after the click action

Comment: actually I want onSelect: function(value), the value to be reused not current date

Comment: @Yasin did u mean..after the datepicker function ..you are not getting the value of currentDate

Comment: @sashi: Yes. I get a value called undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
jQuery(function() {
    var currentDate; //just declare it here.
    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        onSelect: function(value) { 
            alert('The chosen date is ' + value); 
            currentDate= Math.round(Date.parse(value)/ 1000);
        } 
    });

    // TODO
    // on select of a time value trigger the action 
    jQuery("#timepicker").timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i'}) 
    val = jQuery("#timepicker").val();
    currentTime= Math.round(Date.parse(val)/ 1000);

    var t1 = new Date(currentTime * 1000);
    var t2 = new Date(1364598000 * 1000);
    var t3 = new Date(t2.getFullYear(), t2.getMonth(),   t2.getDate(),
                         t1.getHours(),    t1.getMinutes(), t1.getSeconds(), t1.getMilliseconds());
    console.log(t3);
    var timestamp = t3.getTime() / 1000;
});
```

Just declare it outside so that it can be accessed outside of datepicker method.